# How to share a python instance across files?

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused about how the Python import works. I have a large project and I want to share a class instance across some files.
Say, in file-A, I initialized an instance:

```
class SharedClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print('initialing')

    def do(self):
        print('do sth')

shared_instance = SharedClass()
```

Then, in file-B and file-C, I would like to access the `shared_instance` without initializing it again. How can I achieve this?

Currently, I simply use `from file-A import shared_instance` in file-B and file-C. The import works well and I can call the `do` method in file-B and file C.

However, I see two `initialing` in the output which means the class got initialized twice. Avoiding multiple initializations can save much time.

Comment: It sounds like you're running multiple separate Python programs that happen to share the A source file. You can't share objects between separate programs.

Comment: That, or maybe you've got a circular import involving the `__main__` module, or one of a few other situations where the same file would get run twice in the same program.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That still wouldn't initialize the instance twice.

Comment: @ruohola: It would - if `a.py` has `import b` in it and `b.py` has `import a` in it, and you run `python a.py`, then the body of `a.py` gets executed twice, once as the `__main__` module and once as the `a` module. This is one of the awkward consequences of how the whole `__main__` thing was designed.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yea you're actually completely right. That's probably actually what's happening here.

Comment: Are you merely trying to avoid rerunning the same boillerplate code twice, or are you trying to somehow pass state between the code processing file-B and the code processing file-C? (if so, what state exactly?)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Finally, I figured out why 'initialing' got logged out several times. I inspected my code and no circular import involved. Then I created some experimental files for testing. Just as @user2357112 supports Monic said, only one instance initialized.  Then I realized that I am spawning many child processes. Each process has its own shared instance. Passing an argument to suppress the initialization in the child processes solve the problem. Thank you all. These answers are really helpful in pinpoint the issue.